# Why this assemble code occur Segmentation Fault?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

Why this code gives segmentation fault?
(It coded by Intel Assemble syntax)

The result is like this.

```
return value : 80






[Dump]
eax : 0x00000012
ebx : 0x00000004
ecx : 0x00000400
edx : 0x4010a980
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I think I have enough code to prevent Segmentation Fault.
Every function has prologue and epilogue to maintain stack memory.

But, It occur Segmentation Fault error.

[Additional Note]
If I remove the code 'mov     ebx,    4', then segmentation fault error had been removed. (But the result is not fit to my intention)

```
extern printf

segment .data
dumpmsg db      10,10,10,10,10,10,'[Dump]',10,'eax : 0x%0.8x',10,'ebx : 0x%0.8x',10,'ecx : 0x%0.8x',10,'edx : 0x%0.8x',10,00
msg     db      'return value : %d', 10, 00

segment .bss

segment .text
global  main
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,    esp

        push    20
        call    pig
        add     esp,    4

        push    eax
        push    msg
        call    printf

        call    print_x
        leave
        ret

pig:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,    esp

        mov     eax,    [ebp+8]
        mov     ebx,    4
        mul     ebx

        leave
        ret

print_x:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,    esp

        push    edx
        push    ecx
        push    ebx
        push    eax
        push    dumpmsg
        call    printf

        leave
        ret
```

Comment: Your posting is devoid of details. You haven't given us any information on the machine it's executing on, what assembler or platform you're using, and so on.

Comment: @Dai I use Nasm on redhat 6.4. Thank you for answering

Comment: @lurker I try to restore the stack after using printf, but the result was same(Segmentation Fault). Thank you for answering

Comment: If I remove the code 'mov ebx, 4', then segmentation fault error had been removed. (But the result is not fit to my intention)

Comment: My best guess would probably be that you are violating the _CDECL_ calling convention. `main` is a normal function that must follow the convention where _EAX_, _ECX_, and _EDX_ can be destroyed but _EBX_ must be preserved. your `main` modifies _EBX_ (via `pig`) but never restores it before `main` does a _RET_. Try to save _EBX_ when `main` starts and restore it before the _RET_ and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for comment. This question has solved!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I remove the code 'mov ebx, 4', then segmentation fault error had been removed. (But the result is not fit to my intention)

The `EBX` register is callee-save in nearly all x86 calling conventions. That means that a leaf function cannot clobber its value. If it needs to use `EBX`, it must save its original value at the top of the function and restore it at the end. This is usually accomplished with `PUSH`+`POP` instructions to save the register's value on the stack.

Your `pig` function is clobbering `EBX` with the `mov ebx, 4` instruction, but it is *not* taking care to save and restore its original value. This violates the calling convention, which matters because you are interoperating with C code.

The fix is simple:

```
pig:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,    esp
    push    ebx

    mov     eax,    [ebp+12]
    mov     ebx,    4
    mul     ebx

    pop     ebx
    leave
    ret
```

Or, just use the `ECX` register to hold the divisor, since this one is caller-save (and thus free to clobber):

```
pig:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,    esp

    mov     eax,    [ebp+12]
    mov     ecx,    4
    mul     ecx

    leave
    ret
```

> Every function has prologue and epilogue to maintain stack memory.

This really isn't necessary. The `pig` function doesn't use the stack at all, except to retrieve a parameter, so you could write it simply as:

```
pig:
    mov     eax,    [esp+4]
    mov     ecx,    4
    mul     ecx
    ret
```

The use of the base pointer (`EBP`) could be similarly elided from other functions, even those that use the stack, by using the stack pointer (`ESP`) directly. This is the same optimization that compilers will make to free up `EBP` as an additional register and save the prologue/epilogue bloat. But if you are more comfortable doing it this way, then it doesn't hurt anything except performance.

What *is* essential is that you follow the calling convention. The `EAX`, `EDX`, and `ECX` registers are free to clobber inside of a leaf function; all the rest of them need to be explicitly saved and restored to their original values. When you allocate space on the stack, you need to make sure to free it. How you do so is flexible, whether it's with `sub esp, xx`…`add esp, xx` or the prologue...epilogue you have.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers. Your answers helped us solve the problem. :>